# SSH Tunneling on a WS connection

Tags: ssh, websocket, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

I have a Wes server running on a domain, say `wss://abc.xyz`
I cannot directly access it from my local machine, but I can access a machine say IP is (10.5.10.10) which can access this `wss://abc.xyz`.

How do I setup a SSH tunnel here so that my local will connect to the WebSocket server via this intermediate machine?